# Quero testar meu site teste no meu tablet e queria saber como

Tags: html

Queria testar diretamente em um dispositivo mobile, para tirar minhas duvidas !

Comment: O chrome tem uma opção de testar como se estivesse em um dispositivo móvel. Mas se quiser testar diretamente no dispositivo, qual é o problema? Não é só abrir o site?

Comment: Dê mais de como está seu ambiente. Seu site está em uma rede local? Na internet? Que dificuldades está tendo?

Comment: Rodrigo meu site está no wampserver !

Comment: jeferson o meu site abre no navegador, mas queria testar diretamente no meu tablet.

Comment: acho que a pergunta está na fronteira do "fechar" ou "aceitar".. então marquei um positivo para equilibrar..

Comment: Não precisa colocar resolvido no título, basta aceitar a resposta(marcar o sinal verde),  [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá pode ser feito pelo mas algumas vezes não fica perfeito.

Eu gosto muito de usar esse aqui, tem os dispositivos principais em termos de resolução..

http://mobiletest.me/ipad_mini_emulator/?u=http://papoinformal.com.br

Se precisar acessar do seu Wamp faz o seguinte.

Entendi agora. Nesse caso vamos lá. Conecte a mesma rede ( seu pc e seu tablet ), ou na mesma wifi. Quando você cria um Wamp server ele cria um IP na sua rede para o seu site ( APACHE ). Siga essas instruções para divulgar isso para outros dispositivos na mesma rede. (http://www.seucurso.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=343:como-configurar-o-wamp-para-receber-acessos-externos&catid=907:internet&Itemid=71 )
Tenha em mente que sua pasta c:/wamp/www é igual a localhost ou igual ao IP do seu computador. Então se colocar em uma pasta como /meusite no browser localhost/meusite

Comment: Gostei desse site, mas, queria testar diretamente em meu tablete ! O meu site teste esta no server wampserver.

Comment: Entendi agora. Nesse caso vamos lá. Conecte a mesma rede ( seu pc e seu tablet ), ou na mesma wifi.

Quando você cria um Wamp server ele cria um IP na sua rede para o seu site ( APACHE ). Siga essas instruções para divulgar isso para outros dispositivos na mesma rede. (http://www.seucurso.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=343:como-configurar-o-wamp-para-receber-acessos-externos&catid=907:internet&Itemid=71)

Comment: Tenha em mente que sua pasta c:/wamp/www é igual a localhost ou igual ao IP do seu computador. Então se colocar em uma pasta como /meusite no browser http://localhost/meusite

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda me ajudou muito !

Comment: Gilmar Ajuda o casta baixa aqui dá um up na minha resposta vou colocar informações adicionais.

Answer (score 3):

Digite o IP da sua máquina.

### MAC

Se sim, vai em Preferências de Sistema e Rede. Veja seu IP.

Digite o IP na barra de endereço do navegador no tablet.

http://192.168.1.4/nome_do_site

### Windows

Entra no CMD (Prompt de Comando), digite `ipconfig`.

Procure seu **IP**.

Digite esse **IP** no navegador do tablet:

http://192.168.1.4/nome_do_site

Comment: mas meu site está no servidor wampserver no meu pc

Comment: Então Mano... Isso que eu estou falando... Você vai acessar seu PC por IP...

Comment: Talvez seja necessario configuarar o apache para receber requests externos. A ideia é essa mesma, pois o servidor wamp e o tablet devem estar na mesma rede, acredito eu.

Comment: valeu, vou testar aqui

Comment: @rray, eu acho que o **wamp** já vem assim... mas é verdade. Não falei nada da rede, acho que é o mínimo.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode verificar o design responsivo diretamente no seu navegador chrome sem baixar nem acessar nenhuma aplicação especifica:

Com o seu site aberto:
Pressione F12 ou clique com o botão direito do mouse e depois selecione `inspecionar elemento`, note que logo acima na barra pequena existe um icone de um celular, clique nele e atualize a pagina. (em vermelho)

Apos fazer isso note que do lado esquerdo existe uma pequena lista de dispositivos para você testar, basta clicar no nome e selecionar o modelo do aparelho.(em verde)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

se quiser verificar algum tamanho/aparelho exato que não esteja listado você pode clicar, segurar e arrastar as bordas para ajustar o tamanho.

Comment: valeu pela ajuda

Comment: @GilmarSantos se puder marque ao lado que a resposta ajudou e esta correta.